# In Paraview, how to change the datafile filename of the state to create a snapshot from a given datafile and state?

Tags: python, paraview

I am currently able to visualize correctly in ParaView a .vtp file for each time step of a simulation, and to print a screenshot for each. I want to do that in batch, but I want to keep the same state for each one (view point, filters applied, etc). I have already saved the state into a .psvm file , and I tried to write a python script which, after being run by pvbatch, will (hopefully) print the screenshots. But, unfortunately, it is not working. I tried to change the filename in the state by processing the state file and doing a search and replace, but still it is not working. For instance, it keeps plotting the first data input only, even if the current file is different (altough GetSources() shows an always increasing list of sources). I use ParaView 3.14.0 in Snow Leopard. I am sure this is easy, but I am overwhelmed with the large amount of info about python and paraview with no reference to this particularissue. Please, please, any advice is greatly welcome, and I am sorry if this has been answered previously (I looked at google, the paraview mailing list, and here). Below is my script, which can also be found at http://pastebin.com/4xiLNrS0 . Furthermore, you can find some example files and state in http://goo.gl/XjPpE .

```
#!/bin/python
import glob, string, os, commands
from paraview.simple import *

#help(servermanager)
# vtp files are inside the local subdir DISPLAY
files = (commands.getoutput("ls DISPLAY/data-*.vtp | grep -v contacts")).split()

# process each file
for filename in files:
    fullfn = commands.getoutput("ls $PWD/" + filename)
    fn = filename.replace('DISPLAY/', '')
    #os.system("cp ../dem_git/addons/paraview_state.pvsm tmp.pvsm")
    os.system("cp ~/Desktop/state.pvsm tmp.pvsm")
    os.system("sed -i.bck 's/DATA.vtp/" + fullfn.replace('/','\/') + "/1' tmp.pvsm") # replace first intance with full path
    os.system("sed -i.bck 's/DATA.vtp/" + fullfn.replace('/','\/') + "/1' tmp.pvsm") # replace second intance with full path
    os.system("sed -i.bck 's/DATA.vtp/" + fn + "/1' tmp.pvsm") # replace third with just the filename path
    servermanager.LoadState("tmp.pvsm")
    pm = servermanager.ProxyManager()
    reader = pm.GetProxy('sources', fullfn)
    reader.FileName = fullfn
    reader.FileNameChanged()
    reader.UpdatePipeline()

    view = servermanager.GetRenderView()
    SetActiveView(view)
    view.StillRender()

    WriteImage(filename.replace(".vtp", ".png"))
    os.system("rm -f tmp.pvsm")
    os.system("rm -f tmp.pvsm.bck")

    Delete(reader)
```

Comment: @Chris: Thanks a lot, I forgot to do that important thing. I just did that. EDIT: I did not accepted just any answer, but those I am currently using :)

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question, but I had exactly the same problem recently and couldn't find any answers either.  All you need to do is add `Delete(view)` after `Delete(reader)` for your script to work.